# Terminal rendering Korean characters as question marks in boxes

Tags: terminal

[image: question marks]

Code is

```
with open("test.csv", 'a') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in pre_list1:
        row.decode('utf-8')
        print row
```

I want the question marks to show their true values, essentially. These boxes are supposed to be Korean letters. I am not sure if I have to download a language pack for my terminal. I don't know how though. Thanks!

Here is the locale:
[image: locale window]

Comment: You have a locale problem.  Your terminal needs to be set to use, presumably, UTF-8 (or a Korean-specific character set), and you need to ensure that's set in your LANG environment variable, etc.  You need an appropriate Korean font available, too.

Comment: `bash` is only a shell -- it isn't involved in rendering fonts; that's the job of the terminal you're interacting with bash through, which is a completely different/separate/unrelated tool. (Which is to say, "bash terminal" is not a thing that exists; you have a terminal, bash is the shell you're currently running in it, but the terminal and the shell are completely different software, and you could use each without the other).

Comment: ...questions about configuring your terminal are probably more appropriate for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), and should *definitely* include details about which terminal you're using. (GNOME Terminal? KTerm? xterm? wxterm? ITerm? etc, etc, etc)

Comment: Also, when you start a program from bash and it writes its output to stdout -- as your Python is doing -- absent something like a command substitution, that output is **not** written to bash, instead, it's read directly to the terminal itself; bash has nothing to do with how it's interpreted, rendered and displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the system locale from English to Korean.